# Transposing a table dynamically

Tags: sql-server

I have a select with my table design.

The select looks like this:

```
COLUMN_NAME DATA_TYPE   CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH    IS_NULLABLE 
  item_no        char               15                     NO
 year_id         int                NULL                   NO 
  month_id       int                NULL                   YES 
.
.
```

I want to change (rows to columns and columns to rows) like this:

```
item_no   year_id   month_id ...
char        int      int  
15           NULL     NULL 
NO           NO       YES
```

I have read about the function called "pivot" in sql.  Can I use this to do that I want?

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. If this is just a display device, you should do this in the UI/presentation layer and not the database. Otherwise I'm not quite sure what you're after

Comment: thanks for quick reply, I'm trying to migrate and my boss asked me to keep the structure of the table in excel, as I later asked to rebuild and table data in another database (without wizard ...) because they want to validate the data before migrating it to be consistent.